# Node/React app works fine locally but getting 502 error over the internet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I recently was able to connect a node server with my react app after running the `npm run build` command. When running my application locally with `node server` everything works fine after adding the build folder to my public folder. ( I created this app using `create-react-app` and have not changed the directory structure besides moving build into public and creating `server.js` in main directory)

However when I push these changes on to my NGINX web server I get a 502 bad gateway error. 
Prior to adding the build folder my server was running fine it just didn't render JSX elements. Now I can render locally using only the node command but my online server is completely down.

Here is the code of `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '/public/build')));


// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    console.log('get root')    
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , "/public/build/index.html"));

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

Here are the error logs

```
2020/02/13 05:03:22 [error] 7422#7422: *4468 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.84.158.175, server: anthonyjimenez.me, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "anthonyjimenez.me"
2020/02/13 05:25:51 [error] 7422#7422: *4477 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.84.158.175, server: anthonyjimenez.me, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "anthonyjimenez.me"
```

Comment: Nginx is not able to connect to upstream. Try `curl <node-server-ip>:3000` from nginx server to check whether it is able to connect to node's server and please update me whether Nginx and node are in same machine or not?

Comment: @Shubhamoli   node and Nginix are on the same machine I have been able to run other applications and this one on my server before. is there any specific location in the server to run this command?

Comment: Is your Node server running when you are fetching your page?...... you can confirm by `ps -ef | grep node` to check whether Node's running or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed location block proxy_pass to use IPs: proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000 (not proxy_pass http://localhost:5000).

Comment: you mean in nginx proxy pass? what is the difference between 127.0.0.1 vs localhost?